# MRTK OpenXR crashing with HTC Vive Cosmos

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, mrtk, openxr

I'm creating Steam VR app and using MRTK 2.8 OpenXR I'm getting following error with crash on HTC Vive Cosmos though working good on oculus quest 2. Using both devices for streaming only

```
[XR] [MROpenXR][Error  ][18:13:29.036536][tid:1c54] SceneComputer_computeThread_ComputeSceneAsync_XrFailure Function=operator () Result=XR_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
[XR] [MROpenXR][Error  ][18:13:29.036536][tid:1c54] SceneComputer_computeThread_ComputeSceneAsync_XrFailure Function=operator () Result=XR_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
[XR] [MROpenXR][Error  ][18:13:29.036536][tid:1c54] SceneComputer_computeThread_ComputeSceneAsync_XrFailure Function=operator () Result=XR_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
[XR] [MROpenXR][Error  ][18:13:29.036536][tid:1c54] SceneComputer_computeThread_ComputeSceneAsync_XrFailure Function=operator () Result=XR_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
Crash!!!
```

I've tried to update OpenXr plugin also tried to reduce the depth submission mode to 16bit